# Можно считать эти предложения условными?

Tags: синтаксис

(1) *Я без еды продержусь, была бы вода.* (=если бы была вода)

(2) *Попадет в чужые руки, потеряется.* (=если попадет в чужые руки)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Это **БСП**  с условным значением, причем условная часть не на  первом, как обычно, а **на втором месте**. Сравнить: Ужин не нужен, был бы обед (посл.).

2) Также **БСП** с условно-следственным значением, но тогда надо ставить тире: Попадет в чужие руки - потеряется.

Если оставить запятую, то второе предложение распространяет первое (перечислительная интонация, последовательность **взаимообусловленных** событий).

Answer (score 1):

Условные предложения - сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными условия. Ваши примеры такими являются (Вы сами привели в скобках примеры с союзом *если*). От главной части можно задать вопрос к придаточной "при каком условии".